# why group by and count command return me such result?

Tags: sql-server, group-by, count

```
speed ram model
500    64   1
500   64    2
500   32    3
900   128   4
600   128   5
700   32    6
700   64    7

select speed,ram from rrr  group by speed,ram having count(speed)>1
```

result :

```
speed  ram
500    64
```

why the result is  this?
but i expect the following result:

```
speed  ram
500    32
500    64
700     32
700     64
```

because there are three 500,two 700 records
Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 0):

You group by ram and speed, this regroups row having the same ram attribute AND the same speed attribute. In your model, only rows 1 and 2 are in this case. Then your `HAVING` condition keeps only the groups with more than 2 rows in it, so it remains only your group with rows 1 and 2.

I don't understand what you're trying to do exactly but the result you want looks more like `Select speed, ram from rrr where speed in (Select speed group by speed having count(*) > 1)`

Answer (score 0):

`group by speed,ram`  creates the following groups

```
speed  ram
------------
500    64   
500    32    
900    128   
600    128   
700    32    
700    64
```

`count` function of `having` clause is applied to the *whole of the group*. Thus it doesn't matter if you write `count(speed)`, `count(*)` or `count(ram)`. They all return the same value.

See this [**demo**](https://rextester.com/MXAV7397)

The only group with a population bigger than 1 is `500, 64`, hence the result that you get.

You can achieve the expected result using a window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT speed, ram
FROM (
   SELECT speed, ram, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY speed) AS cnt
   FROM mytable) t
WHERE t.cnt > 1
```

Note the `PARTITION BY` clause of the window function: it groups by just `speed`.

[**Demo here**](https://rextester.com/SGSBZ97634)

Comment: I get it,thank u for your explanation.So when we want to group for only one column,we have to use partition,right?

Comment: @user11109122 When you want to group by *only one* column then you use *this and only this* column in the `PARTITION BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are grouping on speed and ram, so to be in the same group both values must be equal.

The result of `select speed,ram, count(speed) from rrr  group by speed,ram` would be

```
speed ram count
500   64    2
500   32    1
900   128   1
600   128   1
700   32    1
700   64    1
```

The only row having `count(speed) > 1` is the row `500 64`

To obtain what you expect use this query:

```
SELECT Distinct speed, ram
FROM rrr
 INNER JOIN (SELECT speed FROM rrr GROUP BY speed HAVING count(*) > 1) T
 ON T.speed = rrr.speed
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    create table #temp (speed int,ram int,model int)
    insert into #temp values (500  ,  64 ,  1)
    insert into #temp values (500  , 64  ,  2)
    insert into #temp values (500  , 32  ,  3)
    insert into #temp values (900  , 128 ,  4)
    insert into #temp values (600  , 128 ,  5)
    insert into #temp values (700  , 32  ,  6)
    insert into #temp values (700  , 64  ,  7)
    select speed ,(ram) as ram,count(ram) as RamCount from #temp group by  speed ,ram having count(ram)>=1
    order by 1
    drop table #temp
```

[image]